# Data annotation validation attribute - mandatory set (i.e. one of many is required)

Tags: c#, validation, data-annotations

We want to use data annotation validation attributes to express that within a certain property set at least one is required.

E.g.:

```
class X
{
    [Set("Set1", Validation=typeof(RequiredAttribute))]
    public string A { get; set; }

    [Set("Set1", Validation=typeof(RequiredAttribute))]
    public string B { get; set; }
}
```

Which would mean that either `A` or `B` must be set. Is something like that already existing?

If not, is there a chance that you can reach the parent object of the object-to-validate in a custom data annotation validation attribute so that we can do that ourselves? Currently we only get either `A` or `B` and have no chance to reach the other.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but not that way. You need to make your class part of the `IValidatableObject` interface (it's also from the DataAnnotations namespace).

Then you can implement a validation function in which you can check the validity using your own business logic.

Note: The name and signature of the `Validate` method are fixed, as they come from the interface.

```
public class Actor : AbstractDataholder, IValidatableObject
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if(string.IsnullorWhiteSpace(this.A) && string.IsnullorWhiteSpace(this.B))
             return new ValidationResult("NOT VALID");            
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That's our current workaround solution, however, we would like to generalize the concept into an attribute in order to have nice code reuse.

Comment: This solution is prone to errors as you easily can mess up the if statement.

Comment: Yep. But you can make a new class that derives from `IValidatableObject`, implements a more general Validate, and use that derived class as a base class for inheriting entities from.

Comment: @D.R. Any solution is error prone if you allow for the option of the business logic being incorrect.

Comment: We do not want to derive our DTOs from a base class just because it requires validation. I don't think that's good design.

Comment: It is more error prone to define the validation logic in a non-declarative way (according to my experience).

Comment: Nonetheless, it is a solution. Whether you prefer another one is your choice. But as far as I understand it, attributes only work on the level of a singular property. Any logic based on how different properties relate to eachother needs to be handled at class level. As far as I've encountered.